# How to call bind function in wordpress actions or hooks

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, actions

I have made a class file in my plugin folder.
Then I wrote,

```
class Sample{

  function footer_content(){
    echo "show any data";
  }

}
```

Then I added the function **footer_content** to wordpress footer by using **add_action** command. But it didn't show anything. maybe I am missing something in this, as it is not working.

```
add_action('wp_footer', Sample::footer_content());
```

Comment: Is that actually working? Try `add_action('wp_footer', array('Sample', 'footer_content'));` instead and make sure your class is available when you call `add_action`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's reference from [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_add_action_with_a_class)

> To use the add_action hook when your plugin or theme is built up using
>   classes, add $this to your add_action call together with the function
>   name within that class, like so:

```
class MyPluginClass {

    public function __construct() {
         //add your actions to the constructor!
         add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_posts' ) );
    }

    public function save_posts() {
         //do stuff here...
    }
}
```